# INSERT INTO not writing into database?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to write info into a db table and it's not working at all. i've been messing with it for hours. maybe if someone looks at the code they'll see something i missed.

my logic is it connects to the db server, opens database mydb, goes to table mod, and writes to id, fname, and lname, then closes the connection.

also, id is set to auto_increment. from what i can tell it should work but it doesn't.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('mydb', $con);

//assign
$query = "INSERT INTO 'mod' (id, fname, lname) VALUES ('', 'bill', 'smith')";
if (!$query){ 
dir ("Unable to create the record:" . mysql_error()); 
exit; 
}
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Do you need the `''` around mod?

Comment: It is apparent you have messed around with it =) The if ( !$query ) is checking a string value for false. And the position of mysql_query is a bit late in relation to that if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are making miskate in referencing the tablename. It should be `` `mod ``` instead of 'mod'. i.e ` [backtick] not '[single quote].

and second error is with your die statement...instead of dir it should be die....

```
INSERT INTO `mod` (id, fname, lname) VALUES ('', 'bill', 'smith');
```

Next you can also skip inserting value for id field which is autoincreament

so it can be

```
INSERT INTO `mod` (fname, lname) VALUES ('bill', 'smith');
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no quotes around 'mod'

//edit:
Also, the `if (!query)` part isn't really useful at that moment because it is checking the string, not the result. You should check the result of `mysql_query()` and if that failed you should output an error message.

Comment: Any errors? Try `echo mysql_error()` after the `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mod (fname, lname) VALUES ('bill', 'smith')";
```

Your auto increment id will be added by the database automatically.

**UPDATE**

Your error code should look like this to work:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mod (fname, lname) VALUES ('bill', 'smith')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to call [mysql_query](http://uk.php.net/mysql_query) to execute query (to see the mysql_error).

Comment: isn't that what i did? mysql_query($query);

Comment: You execute the query AFTER you do the if(!$query) check and then output the mysql_error(). By the time you do the if(!$query) $query variable is still a string and will always evaluate as true. Also you misspelled 'die' to 'dir'...

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mod SET fname='bill', lname='smith'";
```

And the `id` column would autoincrement magically.

Comment: Yep, this can also be achieved by using `(fname, lname) VALUES ('bill', 'smith')`